# How to disable the default Servlet in Karaf?

Tags: servlets, apache-karaf

I am new to Karaf and I am trying to get the default servlet to stop listening:

[image]

I managed to stop all the other things which I do not need by stopping their respective bundles, but for the default servlet I am unable to figure out how to stop it.

Currently it replys:

> No services have been found.

Question: where can I disable the default servlet for the root dir?

---

Edit: We would like to have whiteboard serve an angular site and its ressources dirctly from /. Currenlty ResourceServlet default tries to find javascript files in its bundle ressoures (not a chance...). How do we get the default Servlet to stop bothering us? :)

Comment: I created https://ops4j1.jira.com/browse/PAXWEB-1245 to track this problem. Quick answer is - you can't "disable" this default servlet, as it's registered by default in pax-web.

Comment: @GrzegorzGrzybek alternatively: is there a way to make the default servlet not interfere with our requests to /? (see also edit) Thank you for your support!

Comment: You can simply grab an instance of HttpService and register some Servlet under `/*` path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to disable the default servlet. Instead a new Servlet has to be registered under the `/` path. This servlet will have precedence.